# Silverlight HyperlinkButton inside RadTreeView

Tags: silverlight, treeview, radtreeview

I use the RadTreeView to display a navigation; therefore, I need to show some HyperlinkButtons. I've got two issues:

1) Clicking the HyperlinkButton doesn't set the 'selected' state from the RadTreeViewItem (it seems like the HyperlinkButton won't bubble the click event up to the RadTreeViewItem?)

2) The HyperlinkButton is not at full width

Because of issue #2, I can select the RadTreeViewItem by clicking right next to the HyperlinkBytton, but this only selects the item and no navigation is triggered (which makes sense, because I didn't click the HyperlinkButton, just the item). But I want to be able to navigate by clicking anywhere; therefore, the HyperlinkButton needs to be at full width.

Can you please provide me some tips?

Thanks in advance for your help!!!